# Adonis js how to check status before making user loggedin

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I want to check if user status is active or not and want to login the user only if status='active'. Currently I am trying like this but it doesn't work

```
try{
   const user= await auth.attempt(data.email,data.password).where('status', 'active')
   return user
 }catch(e){
    return response.status(401).json(
     {
       'msg': 'Invalid email or password. Please try again.'
     }
   )
 }
```

Is there anything to check different columns in the user table?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer from adonis.js discor group. I need to use something like this

```
auth.query(function (query) {
        query.where('status', 'active')
}).attempt(data.email,data.password)
```